# Don't see bundle content with VisualVM with OSGi

Tags: java, profiling, osgi, equinox, visualvm

I try to profile some equinox OSGi bundles. I set up my visualVM like descripted [here](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/07/tip-profile-osgi-application-visualvm/).
I'm able to start my application and visualVM. Than I connect and start profiling. Everything seems to work. But if check the call tree. All I see is the Thread.run call. The method I would like to messure is within this thread. It looks like that I am not able to see any plugins written by myself.

These are my VM arguments:

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Dosgi.console.enable.builtin=true 
-Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=org.netbeans.lib.profiler,org.netbeans.lib.profiler.* 
-Xbootclasspath/a:PathToVisualVM\profiler\lib\jfluid-server.jar
```

I checked already [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326113/visualvm-profile-cpu-but-run-methods-disturb) but it didn't help me. If you need more information just let me know. I just don't know where to look.

Does anybody have an idea why I'm not able to see the bundle content within the Snapshot?

Sincereley

Comment: Did you check the profiler’s filter settings? Maybe it’s related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619610/visualvm-not-showing-any-methods-called-for-cpu-performance-profiling)?

Comment: Yes I did I only filter the default packages like java.* ...

Comment: Try once without any filter, just to be sure…

Comment: I do not know how VisualVM works but I had problems with debugging and code coverage reports. When any technology with bundle bytecode manipulation via Bundle hook was present, the hashes of the classes was different from the one that the IDE knew about. More specifically: I had problems when aries-proxy and ASM-4 was installed together. After I removed ASM-4, everything worked well.